# Why are recently-closed questions with no reopen votes in the reopen queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

A significant number of these questions have been closed by diamond moderators, so there seems to be zero reason to have it in the reopen queue. These questions have not been edited in the meantime, though I can't speak as to the presence of any flags.

An example is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path), which was closed by Cody Gray ♦. Just 17 hours later (with zero reopen votes), I [received it in the reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22823261).

Is there any reasoning behind this? It's counterintuitive (and wasted effort, at that) to have questions that were closed by a ♦ to be immediately placed into the reopen queue.

Additional examples:

- [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634281/list-of-swagger-ui-alternatives) [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22821726)
- [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle) [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22821415)
- [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/what-is-the-preferred-syntax-for-defining-enums-in-javascript) [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22819051)

Comment: Yeah, that is weird. It wasn't edited or flagged. I see nothing obvious that would justify its being thrown into the review queue. Maybe the system is inherently suspicious of all actions I take?

Comment: I _think_ it started happening in the past couple days. No idea if anything changed on the backend recently. Not all of these are your doing, though! Some were closed by the standard 5 votes.

Comment: Martijn Pieters reminded me of [the third criteria that can put a closed question into the reopen queue: popularity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078). That explains what happened with the original example question, and the additional (non-audit) examples you dug up.

Comment: Hmm...you'd think a moderator's would override the automated system there.

Comment: @jhpratt Not really. If a mod wants it closed for good, they have the ability to lock it.

Comment: @Machavity and/or just straight up delete it

Comment: @CodyGray And now we have the Meta Effect skewing that third criteria even more.. D'oh!

Comment: Funny that the popularity criteria also prevents edits from either the author or third party from putting the question in the reopen queue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are actually *three* criteria by which a closed question can be placed into the reopen review queue:

- An **edit** is made to the body of the question, within 5 days of closure. The edit can be made either by the author, or by a third-party (provided that the third-party was not involved in the question's closure).
- Someone casts a **flag or vote** to reopen the question.
- The question is **sufficiently popular**, as determined by the score of the question itself, the score of the top answer, or the number of views per month (although these specific popularity criteria may have changed since [they were first documented by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078)).

None of the questions you reviewed were edited or flagged since the time of their closure by a moderator, but they *were* popular questions, and that's why the system questioned their closure.

I am conflicted on whether or not this "popularity" criteria is a good idea, but it makes some degree of sense. Some commenters have suggested that a moderator-involved closure should be exempt from community review via this route, but I have to disagree on that. If it's a good idea to have the closure of popular questions double-checked, then that should be equally true when a moderator was involved, if not *more* true, since moderators have a binding vote. Besides the fact that, if a moderator *really* wants something gone, never to come back, they can delete it.

Comment: Are there reopen flags?  I didn't think there were and can't remember that far back.